# Sales force default access

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

What is the default access specifier in sfdc?

eg if you declare a class as:

```
  class MyClass{
      //Code
   }
```

then by default what will be the access specifier for this class?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define an outer class without an access modifier, you must specify public or global. If you try you'll get a compile error:

> Save error: Top-level type must have
>   public or global visibility

Inner classes on the other hand do not require access modifier and are private by default.